# How to create a class-less DSL in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to create a sort of "class-less DSL" for my Ruby project, similar to how step definitions are defined in a Cucumber step definition file or routes are defined in a Sinatra application.

For example, I want to have a file where all my DSL functions are being called:

```
#sample.rb

when_string_matches /hello (.+)/ do |name|
    call_another_method(name)
end
```

I assume it's a bad practice to pollute the global (`Kernel`) namespace with a bunch of methods that are specific to my project. So the methods `when_string_matches` and `call_another_method` would be defined in my library and the `sample.rb` file would somehow be evaluated in the context of my DSL methods.

**Update:** Here's an example of how these DSL methods are currently defined:

The DSL methods are defined in a class that is being subclassed (I'd like to find a way to reuse these methods between the simple DSL and the class instances):

```
module MyMod
  class Action
    def call_another_method(value)
      puts value
    end

    def handle(text)
      # a subclass would be expected to define
      # this method (as an alternative to the 
      # simple DSL approach)
    end
  end
end
```

Then at some point, during the initialization of my program, I want to parse the `sample.rb` file and store these actions to be executed later:

```
module MyMod
  class Parser

    # parse the file, saving the blocks and regular expressions to call later
    def parse_it
      file_contents = File.read('sample.rb')
      instance_eval file_contents
    end

    # doesnt seem like this belongs here, but it won't work if it's not
    def self.when_string_matches(regex, &block)
      MyMod.blocks_for_executing_later << { regex: regex, block: block }
    end
  end
end

# Later...

module MyMod
  class Runner

    def run
      string = 'hello Andrew'
      MyMod.blocks_for_executing_later.each do |action|
        if string =~ action[:regex]
          args = action[:regex].match(string).captures
          action[:block].call(args)
        end
      end
    end

  end
end
```

The problem with what I have so far (and the various things I've tried that I didn't mention above) is when a block is defined in the file, the instance method is not available (I know that it is in a different class right now). But what I want to do is more like creating an instance and eval'ing in that context rather than eval'ing in the `Parser` class. But I don't know how to do this.

I hope that makes sense. Any help, experience, or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit challenging to give you a pat answer on how to do what you are asking to do. I'd recommend that you take a look at the book [Eloquent Ruby](http://eloquentruby.com) because there are a couple chapters in there dealing with DSLs which would probably be valuable to you. You did ask for some info on how these other libraries do what they do, so I can briefly try to give you an overview.

**Sinatra**

If you look into the sinatra code [sinatra/main.rb](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/main.rb#L30) you'll see that it extends `Sinatra::Delegator` into the main line of code. [Delegator](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1744) is pretty interesting..

It sets up all the methods that it wants to delegate

```
delegate :get, :patch, :put, :post, :delete, :head, :options, :template, :layout,
         :before, :after, :error, :not_found, :configure, :set, :mime_type,
         :enable, :disable, :use, :development?, :test?, :production?,
         :helpers, :settings
```

and sets up the class to delegate to as a class variable so that it can be overridden if needed..

```
self.target = Application
```

And the delegate method nicely allows you to override these methods by using `respond_to?` or it calls out to the `target` class if the method is not defined..

```
def self.delegate(*methods)
  methods.each do |method_name|
    define_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
      return super(*args, &block) if respond_to? method_name
      Delegator.target.send(method_name, *args, &block)
    end
    private method_name
  end
end
```

**Cucumber**

Cucumber uses the [treetop language library](http://treetop.rubyforge.org/). It's a powerful (and complex—i.e. non-trivial to learn) tool for building DSLs. If you anticipate your DSL growing a lot then you might want to invest in learning to use this 'big gun'. It's far too much to describe here.

**HAML**

You didn't ask about HAML, but it's just another DSL that is implemented 'manually', i.e. it doesn't use treetop. Basically (gross oversimplification here) it reads the haml file and processes each line [with a case statement](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/lib/haml/parser.rb#L206)...

```
def process_line(text, index)
  @index = index + 1

  case text[0]
  when DIV_CLASS; push div(text)
  when DIV_ID
    return push plain(text) if text[1] == ?{
    push div(text)
  when ELEMENT; push tag(text)
  when COMMENT; push comment(text[1..-1].strip)
  ...
```

I think it used to call out to methods directly, but now it's preprocessing the file and pushing the commands into a stack of sorts. e.g. [the `plain` method](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/lib/haml/parser.rb#L254)

FYI the [definition of the constants](https://github.com/haml/haml/blob/master/lib/haml/parser.rb#L10) looks like this..

```
# Designates an XHTML/XML element.
ELEMENT         = ?%
# Designates a `<div>` element with the given class.
DIV_CLASS       = ?.
# Designates a `<div>` element with the given id.
DIV_ID          = ?#
# Designates an XHTML/XML comment.
COMMENT         = ?/
```

Comment: There's a lot for me to digest there since some of it is a bit over my head, but it's still useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Modules to organize your code. You can add your DSL methods to the `Module` class using the `Module#include` method. Here's how RSpec does it. The last two lines being what you are probably looking for. +1 to @meagar about keeping DSL's simple!

Also as @UncleGene points out, RSpec does pollute Kernel with the DSL methods. I'm not sure how to get around that. If there was another DSL with a `describe` method, it would be hard to determine which `describe` one was using.

```
module RSpec
  module Core
    # Adds the `describe` method to the top-level namespace.
    module DSL
      # Generates a subclass of {ExampleGroup}
      #
      # ## Examples:
      #
      #     describe "something" do
      #       it "does something" do
      #         # example code goes here
      #       end
      #     end
      #
      # @see ExampleGroup
      # @see ExampleGroup.describe
      def describe(*args, &example_group_block)
        RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup.describe(*args, &example_group_block).register
      end
    end
  end
end
extend RSpec::Core::DSL
Module.send(:include, RSpec::Core::DSL)
```

Comment: Does not extend here pollute Kernel? require 'rspec'; puts Kernel.methods.grep /describe/  =>describe.  And I am not sure that polluting Module any better (AFAIU OP was trying to avoid pollution)

Comment: @UncleGene you're right. I'm editing my answer to add this point.

Answer (score 2):

Just define a method called `when_string_matches` which takes a regex as an argument, tests it against whatever "string" you're talking about, and conditionally yields, passing whatever `name` is to its block:

```
def when_string_matches(regex)
   # do whatever is required to produce `my_string` and `name`
   yield(name) if my_string =~ regex
end
```

This is essentially all Ruby DSLs are: Methods with interesting names that often accept blocks.

Comment: ... that are defined on `Kernel`.

Comment: Then change your method definition to store the block it's given, along with any state variables, for later execution.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question with a ton of code samples that I hope better explain my situation. The problem lies with the parsing and eval'ing the file and calling instance methods that aren't available where the block was first defined.

Comment: @Andrew What? You're going about this in the exact wrong manner. Don't parse or eval the file! It's a *Ruby* file, it's just plain ordinary Ruby. You just `require` it, and *Ruby* parses and executes the contents of the file. Ruby DSLs are *Ruby*, not some pseudo-language you have to worry about parsing.

Comment: I can't simply `require` it because the `when_string_matches` method is not defined globally, so you get undefined method errors.

Comment: @Andrew define your methods on Kernel to make them globally available.